# Docker - How to see the logs of running application inside Docker container?

Tags: node.js, docker

I have a Node.js application running inside Docker container in /usr/src/app.

I want to run this application using nohup (nohup node index.js &).

What is the best way to see the output appended to nohup.out for general/debugging purposes?

Do I need to use docker cp all the time to copy to host os. Is there a better way to achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need to use nohup?

Comment: @jsalonen, I am aware that i can simply run node index.js and can use docker logs to see the output to stdout, but curious how to see the log files in case if i have a log file to which output is being written

Comment: Does nohup write to a logfile? What is the name of your logfile?

Comment: it writes to nohup.out file

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Although using logfiles inside container (without volume mounting) is an anti-pattern, you can easily output those files using exec for example along with cat:

```
docker exec -it [CONTAINERID] cat /usr/src/app/nohup.out
```

Better pattern would be to store output into separate [volume-mounted folder](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/#mount-a-host-directory-as-a-data-volume) removing state from inside your container, but would also allow you to access logs directly from host system.

In this specific case, I don't see a need for a separate logfile, and not even for nohup. Just set policy for your container to [restart it automatically](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/start-containers-automatically/) (`--restart always`) instead of nohup.

Comment: anti pattern link is dead as of today

Comment: Removed dead link

Comment: Usage of the command is 

`docker exec [OPTIONS] CONTAINER COMMAND [ARG...]`
Always use CONTAINER (task ID) and not service name. We can use any *nix command for COMMAND. ls will display list of files in the working directory of container.

Answer (score 5):

You do output your logs in

`/dev/stdout` for all normal logs

use `/dev/stderr` to pipe all the errors you have, if your application can differ between normal logs and error logs.

So instead of defining your log like `/var/log/nohup.log` you define the logfile to be `dev/stdout`

Accessing the logs will then be as easy as writing `docker logs <containername>` or `docker-compose logs <servicename>` - if you have started your stack using `docker-compose up` you will see the logs right in front of you anyway - very convenient.

In production grade you want to process the log stream further, look at https://github.com/gliderlabs/logspout

And if you want to go a level deeper, add the ELK stack to it https://logz.io/learn/complete-guide-elk-stack/